# Necessary and sufficient condition for argmax/argmin

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be real variables and let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice-differentiable function with a unique strict global maximum and with a unique maximizer $\mathbf{x}^* = (x_1^*,\dots,x_n^*)$. Assume that $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$, where $f_i$ are twice-differentiable functions. Is there a ***necessary and sufficient condition*** for which
$$
(*) \quad \arg \max_{x_1,\dots,x_n} f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \{ \arg \max_{x_1} f_1(x_1), \dots, \arg \max_{x_n} f_n(x_n) \}
$$
is valid? The same question could be rephrased for $\arg \min$.

Comment: Question was edited to better explain what was actually meant in $(*)$.

Answer (score 1):

A **sufficient** condition and that is if all the $f_i$ are positive and have a strict unique global maximum.

We define $x_i^\star$ as the strict unique global maximum of $f_i$ if $f_i(x_i) < f_i(x_i^\star)$ for all $x_i \neq x_i^\star$. Then for a  factorizable  $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^nf_i(x_i)$ and $\forall_i : x_i \neq x_i^\star, $ and we have
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = f_1(x_1)\cdots f_n(x_n) < f_1(x_1^\star)f_2(x_2)\cdots f_n(x_n) < \cdots < f_1(x_1^\star)\cdots f_n(x_n^\star).$$

While on the other hand we have $f(x_1^\star,\ldots,x_n^\star) = f_1(x_1^\star)\cdots f_n(x_n^\star)$.

Thus $(x_1^\star,\ldots,x_n^\star)$ is the strict global maximum of $f$.

---

EDIT: Another **sufficient** condition is by differentiability. Assume that $f > 0$, then, for any $x_i$, we have that $f_i(x_i) \neq 0$, thus it is or strictly positive or strictly negative.

Say that $\hat{x}_i$ is the unique maximum of $f_i$, that is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f_i(\hat{x}_i) = 0$, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f_i(x_i) \neq  0$ for $x_i \neq \hat{x}_i$. Also, assume second order differentiability at $\hat{x}_i$, such that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2} f_i(\hat{x}_i) < 0$ by the second derivative test.

Then, by Fermat's theorem, 
$$\begin{matrix}f_2(\hat{x}_2)\cdots f_n(\hat{x}_n)  \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f_1(\hat{x}_1) = 0, \\ \vdots \\ f_1(\hat{x}_1)\cdots f_{n-1}(\hat{x}_{n-1})  \cdot  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} f_n(\hat{x}_n) = 0, \\  \end{matrix}$$
Thus, $\hat{x} = (\hat{x}_1,\ldots,\hat{x}_n)$ is a stationary point of $f$. By assumption, it is also the only stationary point of $f$. To see if it is a maximum, the Hessian matrix should have negative eigenvalues. Due to the factorization, the Hessian at $\hat{x}$ is a diagonal matrix, with the $i^{th}$ diagonal entry given by, $$h_{ii} = \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2} f_i(\hat{x}_i)\right)\cdot \prod_{j \neq i} f_j(\hat{x_j}),$$
and we need $h_{ii} < 0$ for all $i$. We assumed that the second order derrivative of $f_i$ is negative, if $\prod_{j \neq i} f_j(\hat{x_j}) > 0$, we find the result that $x^\star = \hat{x}$ is the global maximum of $f$.

---

This reflects the comments mady bo OP, that there are different factorizations possible, especially in interchanging the sign. In $h_{ii}$ we see that sign of $f_i$ does not matter, since we only care about the sign of the product at the position of the global optimum.

Comment: Good answer. Yet, a bit unsatisfying. The thing is that the sign of the various $f_i$ should be not be so stringent, because when you do factorization, there is a bit of freedom in the sign. Take $n=2$ and suppose $f(x_1, x_2) > 0$. I can factorize $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(x_1) f(x_2)$ with both $f_i$ positive, but also $f(x_1,x_2) = (-f_1(x_1))(-f_2(x_2))$. I believe that the true real hypothesis is for the $f_i$ to have a strict unique global maximum; it should work even if $f$ have variable signs. Can you attempt a proof, at least for $f>0$?

Comment: I agree with you on the unsatisfying part, but the problem with the sign is that it turns a maximum in a minimum. Generally,  $\max -f(x) \neq -\max f(x)$.  Thus your counter example does not hold. Unless you allow some flexibility in $(*)$ to generalize it to optima instead of a specific min/max.

Comment: Wait, that's not my point. It is not important if $\max -f(x)$ is equal or not to $-\max f(x)$ (we don't care about that). What we care is if the maximizer is the same (regardless if min is turned into max). My counterexample is the following: given strict uniqueness conditions, $(x_1^*, x_2^*) = \arg \max_{x_1, x_2} f(x_1, x_2) = \arg \max f_1(x_1) f_2(x_2) = \arg \max (-f_1(x_1)) (-f_2(x_2))$. So, you need $f>0$, but you don't need $f_1 >0$ (redefine: $f_1^{new} = - f_1$, so if $f_1>0$, $f_1^{new}<0$), since the _global_ maximizer $(x_1^*, x_2^*)$ is preserved. Hope to have been clear.

Comment: Essentially, my point is that factorization is not unique and there is no "natural" factorization. When it is possible to factorize $f$, there are always multiple choices. Take $f(x_1, x_2) = 1/ ( (x_1^2 +1)^2 (x_2^2 +1)^2 )$. I could factorize it like $f_i^+ = 1/(x_i^2 +1)^2$, but also $f_i^{-} = -1/(x_i^2 +1)^2$ works. Now, $f$ has a unique maximum in $(0,0)$, _regardless_ if I factorize it with $f_i^+$ or $f_i^-$. This means that, if $f>0$, I can prove a statement involving $\arg \max$ without forcing $f_i>0$. The key property is strict uniqueness, like in the example I have given.

Comment: Very good! Twice-differentiability is fine (I edited the question). Now, if you can find a necessary condition, it's perfect. My partial attempt: suppose $f>0$. Most probably this implies that there is at least one factorization where all $f_i>0$; after all, why shouldn't it be possible? Since $f>0$ and it has a strict unique global max, $f$ is bounded from above ($f(x) \leq f(x*)$) and from below. Since $f$ is bounded, ***probably*** (I don't have proof) there exist at least one factorization where all $f_i$ are bounded. Thus, there should be one "special" factorization with bounded $f_i>0$.

Comment: Bounded $f_i>0$ implies it must have at least one maximum somewhere, or be constant. In both cases, argmax $f_i$ can never be empty set. Call $A_i$ the set which is the output of argmax $f_i$. Denote with $|A|$ the cardinality of set $A$. In order for $(*)$ to make sense, a ***necessary*** condition is that $\sum_{i=1}^n |A_i| = n$. But since $A_i$ can never be empty, the only possible way for this to happen is $|A_i|=1$. But this can only be true if $f_i$ has exactly one maximum!